# concatenating two objects without partitioning arrays

Tags: javascript

I'm not sure how to do this so any help would be appreciated. I have two objects I want to combine into one object. I've used the spread operator to do this:

```
newObj = {...obj1, ...obj2};
```

this, for example gives me this:

```
{
  [
    obj1A{
     "item": "stuff",
     "item": "stuff"
    },
    obj1B{
     "item": "stuff",
     "item": "stuff"
    }
  ],
  [
    obj2A{
     "item": "stuff",
     "item": "stuff"
    },
    obj2B{
     "item": "stuff",
     "item": "stuff"
    }
  ]
}
```

But what I want is this:

```
 {
      [
        obj1A{
         "item": "stuff",
         "item": "stuff"
        },
        obj1B{
         "item": "stuff",
         "item": "stuff"
        },
        obj2A{
         "item": "stuff",
         "item": "stuff"
        },
        obj2B{
         "item": "stuff",
         "item": "stuff"
        }
      ]
    }
```

Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: please add valid objects. arrays do not have properties in literal syntax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With proper unique names, you could use [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) and create a new object.

```js
var object1 = { obj1A: { item1: "stuff", item2: "stuff" }, obj1B: { item1: "stuff", item2: "stuff" } },
    object2 = { obj2A: { item1: "stuff", item2: "stuff" }, obj2B: { item1: "stuff", item2: "stuff" } },
    combined = Object.assign({}, object1, object2);
  
console.log(combined);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Of course if that's the shape of the objects, then the original technique would work just as well here: `combined = {...object1, ...object2}`.  So I suspect there's something else going on here.

Comment: @ScottSauyet, actually not in all user agents.

Comment: Oh, I never realized that.  Is it just old IE?

Comment: Thank you.  I've only recently gotten back into working with browsers.  Too much Node lately; it's awfully convenient to be working with a single evergreen agent!

Comment: Accepting this answer as it's correct for the question asked. Though it doesn't solve my problem. I was already using the spread operator, which does the same thing regardless of compatibility. I think I'll post up an other question that's more specific to my issue. Apologies for the generality of the initial question.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jQuery you could do something similar to this https://jsfiddle.net/d11kfd4d/:

```
var a = { 
   propertyOne: 'One',
   propertyTwo: 'Two'
};

var b = { 
   propertyThree: 'Three',
   propertyFour: 'Four'
}

var c = $.extend(a, b);

console.log(c);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a typo (changing this `[]` to this `{}`) and the keys are valids (not repeated), you can use the Spread syntax.

```js
var obj1 = { obj1A: { item: "stuff", item2: "stuff" }, obj1B: { item: "stuff", item2: "stuff" } },
    obj2 = { obj2A: { item: "stuff", item2: "stuff" }, obj2B: { item: "stuff", item2: "stuff" } }
    
console.log({...obj1, ...obj2});
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: The question noted that this did not work.  So I suspect the original objects are not as suggested.  (It's not just a bracket change.)